# Transmit templated objects over the network

Tags: c++, serialization

I am working on a project where we'd like to send objects over the network. These objects are instantiated with templates; we could have `OurClass<double>` or `OurClass<int>` or whatever. I need to send these objects over the net, restore them on the far end, and call methods.

My problem is that if the remote end doesn't know what templated type it will be receiving, it won't know what type to instantiate for deserialization. I've been playing with boost serialization but having no luck.

Can anyone comment on their experiences sending templated objects over the network?

Comment: Objcets can't be templated. Only *types* can.

Comment: you can not send 'templates' over network, but you can send the data with an id first. then the receiver can choose the right one by the id. maybe this could help you.

Comment: This is what's called a "protocol". There needs to be either something in the stream prior to the object that indicates exactly what type the object is (even if it's just an expected structure), or the serialized object needs to contain within itself enough information to uniquely identify the type the object needs to have.

Comment: @twalberg We're writing a library. I don't know what types the user will put in our classes; they could decide to do OurClass<float> or something they themselves defined. So the user will instantiate an object, and then want to have it sent over the network, but my library code has no way of knowing what types were used in instantiating that class. Sorry if this is not well described, I haven't used C++ in ages.

Comment: @John: Unfortunately for you, twalberg is right: you somehow **need** to "tag" your network messages so that the receiving end knows which type it should deserialize, there's no other way around. Maybe you should consider making a traits class for that, providing the specializations for basic C++ types and letting your library users specialize the traits for their own classes?

Comment: @John In that case, any class that might be used in the template probably should be smart enough to serialize/de-serialize itself (i.e. there should be an interface it is required to implement). However either your stream, or the representation of the object itself still must contain sufficient information for the classes to correctly parse a received representation.